# How to make such list in Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-contacts

I have a task to make such list in an Android app
[image]

It's the list with contacts from Contact provider. I have few questions about making of layout:

1. How to make letter headers?(A, B)
2. How to add divider to group of elements
3. How to make letter headers sticky?

I know, that such type of list is quite popular and it's mention in Material Design docs https://material.io/design/components/lists.html#usage So, I hope you will show some RecyclerView methods to achieve my goals or give me a link to similiar example

Comment: you should try yourself before, but anw, here is my solution, first, sort your list, mark the first element and last element of each group, modify item's layout by that.

Answer (score 1):

try this one https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders/blob/master/README.md
it's based on ListView but has 5k+ stars on GitHub, so I think it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

it is simple you need to create an adapter with a header and inside the adapter create another adapter for the numbers list